# ¿Cómo mostrar la fecha de los tres días anteriores a la actual en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

He estado tratando de hacer un código en el que de acuerdo al día en que se ejecute me muestre los días anteriores (digamos que hasta tres). Es decir que si hoy es 18 de agosto, al ejecutar el código me mostraría la fecha del 17 de agosto, 16 de agosto y del 15 de agosto. La cuestión es que lo necesito hacer en una función y lo que he probado ha sido sin mucho éxito.

Así es como lo tenia inicialmente pero necesito encontrar algún modo de que sea automático y que al detectar la fecha del día actual me mostrara los tres dias anteriores a ese.

```
let dia = new Date();
        dia.setDate(dia.getDate()-1);
        console.log(dia)//Me mostraria 17 de agosto

let dia2 = new Date();
            dia2.setDate(dia2.getDate()-2);
            console.log(dia2) //Me mostraria el 16 de agosto
```

Espero haberme hecho entender, si pueden ayudarme les agradecería mucho. Todo cuenta

Comment: ¿Lo quieres tal cual "17 de agosto" o solamente el objeto fecha con los 3 días mencionados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias con ayuda de un ciclo ir restanto a la fecha actual e ir guardando los valores en un array

```js
function obtenerFechas(){
    let fecha = new Date();
    let fechas = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        fechas.push(fecha.getDate()-i);
    }
    return fechas;
}
console.log(obtenerFechas());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esto me funciono como quería!

Answer (score 0):

Si queres mostrar el string de la forma que pedis, podes ir calculando los dias anteriores con un for y concatenar el dia y el mes para formar el string que pedis de la siguiente forma:

```js
 function obtenerDias(){
        const meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto"]
        const hoy = new Date();
        let array = []
    
    
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    
            let aux = new Date(hoy.getFullYear(), hoy.getMonth(), hoy.getDate() - i);
    
            array.push(`${aux.getDate()} de ${meses[aux.getMonth()]}`)
        }
    
        return array;
    
    }
    
    console.log(obtenerDias())
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo usando `moment` y su funcion `add`, en este caso guardando las fechas en un array:

```js
let fechas = [];
for(let i = 3; i >= 1; i--){
    fechas.push(moment(new Date()).add(-i, 'days'));
}

console.log(fechas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```